# Determining correlations of derivatives of a function given only measurements of that function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, regression, applications

Cross-posted from [statistics stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560702/proper-regression-for-determining-correlations-between-derivatives-of-functions):

Say we have a permanent-magnet DC motor that roughly obeys the system equation $\ddot{x}(t) = \alpha \dot{x}(t) + \beta u(t) + \gamma$, where $x(t)$ is the displacement of the rotor, and $u(t)$ the applied voltage, at time $t$.

Say we wish to determine the values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ experimentally.  If we can *only* directly measure $x$, not $\dot{x}$ or $\ddot{x}$, how should we go about estimating these parameters from a set of time-series measurements of $u$ and $x$?

One naive approach is to compute the derivatives through some central finite difference scheme, and then perform an OLS regression - but it is unobvious how the derivative calculation interacts with the regression.  Additionally, I have found in practice that this suffers from a significant amount of regression dilution if the test is allowed to run too long at steady-state (the derivatives vanish here, and so all that's left is the noise).

Is there any more "complete" method for analyzing systems like this that handles the differentiation as part of the construction of the regression model?  Is there a good theory of correlations between derivatives of time-series data?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://ftp.esat.kuleuven.be/pub/SISTA//kdebaban/11-147.pdf) approach to estimate  $\dot{x}$ and $\ddot{x}$?

Comment: I have not!  It looks interesting, and I'll give it a try, but I wonder: is local polynomial fitting a valid solution for differential equations whose solutions are exponential in shape?

Comment: You can try to take logs and recover the derivatives of $x(t)$ from the estimated derivatives of $\ln(x(t))$

Comment: Are you familiar with Kalman filtering?

Comment: @Jose Avilez Yes; the results of this regression are typically being used for estimation of optimal state-space feedback gains for use with a Kalman observer (though we use them for simpler PID control schemes, as well).

Comment: Our Kalman control approach leaves out the dry friction term $\gamma$, which is used for feedforward only.  This term is important in practice on the systems we're controlling, however, so it can't be omitted from the identification routine.

Comment: @user3716267 Great! At first sight, it looks to me that one could write a state-equation for $(x,u)$ with observation errors, and formulate the estimation of $(\alpha , \beta, \gamma )$ as a Kalman filtering problem. Naturally, one would have to work out the details, but, as far as I know, the Kalman framework is sufficiently flexible for estimation problems like these. In fact, the ARIMAX answer given to you can be formulated in a very general state-space time series formulation, after which one could use Kalman-like tools for estimation.

Comment: My lingering concern about the Kalman approach is the handling of the $\gamma$ term, which is strongly nonlinear (the full term is $\gamma \text{sgn}(\dot{x})$, since dry friction opposes the direction of motion).  We've neglected it in our Kalman control schemes for this reason, and instead relied on its presence in the control feedforward to cancel it out.